# blender with openGL 1.3 or lower

Tags: opengl

is there a way to bypass this openGL support, i just need to run this program on low spec computer in purpose.

or maybe there's another suggestion about what program that i can use with OprnGL 1.3

best regards~

Comment: another suggestion... for doing what? afaik, all advanced 3d programs need modern hardware support. 2.76 is the last for opengl 1.4. But maybe you need just some basic function? Anyway, older blender versions are still available here http://download.blender.org/release, you could try to go back in versions until someone works... I can't find docs about any specific old version opengl compatibility, atm.

Comment: In the user preferences under the "System" tab at top right, there are computing options at bottom left.  The very bottom left one will open up a menu that allows you to switch down to "None", or use the CPU.  I haven't tried it myself - in case it won't come back on again!  That might do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.76 does appear to have support for opengl 1, but i thibk that is the CPU doing most of the rendering, and alot of the lighting is miscalculated when loading projects from newer versions of blender(not sure about older ones)